# Find intersection of $|\cos(x)/2|$ and $|\arctan(x)|$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find the intersection for: $$\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{2}\right| = |\arctan(x)|, \  \forall x> 0$$

***my attempt:*** 
I tried to find the value of $x$ as follows; 
$$\frac{\cos(x)}{2} = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$$

Then

$$\frac{1}{\sin(x)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\csc(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$ Then $x$ does not have any answer. 
Is it correct or I made a mistake?

Comment: $arctan\, x$ is not $\frac {\cos\,x } {\sin \, x}$.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Unfortunately I do-not have Latex on my PC now

Comment: You don't need LaTeX on your PC to use it here. Just try typing TeX commands for mathematical expressions *inside dollar signs*. E.g. typing `$y=\sin x$` here gives $y=\sin x$.

Comment: You can use the TeX commands here, for instance this is $$x$$

Comment: Ask the question clearly. Better upload the photo of the question.

Comment: By a numerical method we get $$x\approx 0.4761470147$$

Comment: Could you please let me know how I can solve it in a mathematical way

Comment: I found that $arctan(x)$  = $arcsin(x/√(x^2+1))$

Comment: You could perhaps use [Fixed Point Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) on $$ \tan\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{2}\right) = x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Parcly Taxel already answered, you need a numerical metod to solve the equation, that is to say to find the zero of function
$$y=\cos (x)-2\tan^{-1}(x)$$

Remember that is already the case for the "simple" $x=\cos(x)$.

Using Newton method, and being lazy, I shall start with $x_0=0$ and the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.00000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.50000000000000000000 \\
 2 & 0.47609308186884695044 \\
 3 & 0.47614701448567249514 \\
 4 & 0.47614701474806253971
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

You could get *approximate* solutions expanding $y$ as Taylor series around, say, $x= 0$ and get for example
$$y=1-2 x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{2
   x^5}{5}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{2 x^7}{7}+\frac{x^8}{40320}-\frac{2
   x^9}{9}-\frac{x^{10}}{3628800}+O\left(x^{11}\right)$$ Now, using series reversion, this would give
$$x=t-\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{11 t^3}{24}-\frac{91 t^4}{192}+\frac{1141
   t^5}{1920}-\frac{18937 t^6}{23040}+\frac{372539 t^7}{322560}-\frac{8694019
   t^8}{5160960}+\frac{33483283 t^9}{13271040}-\frac{793236041
   t^{10}}{206438400}+O\left(t^{11}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{1-y}2$.

Making $y=0$, that is to say $t=\frac 12$, you should end with
$$x=\frac{902783482711}{1902536294400}\approx 0.474516$$ I suppose that you see how simple is Newton method for this problem.

**Edit**

There is another possible way to *approximate* the solution at the price of a simple linear equation.

Instead of using Taylor series, use the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant. As a function of $n$, the numerator and the solution of it are listed below
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 n & \text{numerator} & x_{(n)}=& x_{(n)}\approx \\
 1 & 1-\frac{9 x}{4} & \frac{4}{9} &    0.444444 \\
 2 & 1-\frac{56 x}{27} & \frac{27}{56} &   0.482143 \\
 3 & 1-\frac{67 x}{32} & \frac{32}{67} &   0.477612 \\
 4 & 1-\frac{704 x}{335} & \frac{335}{704} &   0.475852 \\
 5 & 1-\frac{20711 x}{9856} & \frac{9856}{20711}   & 0.475882 \\
 6 & 1-\frac{913376 x}{434931} &    \frac{434931}{913376} & 0.476180 \\
 7 & 1-\frac{15344777 x}{7307008} &    \frac{7307008}{15344777} & 0.476189 \\
 8 & 1-\frac{96681728 x}{46034331} &    \frac{46034331}{96681728} & 0.476143 \\
 9 & 1-\frac{553781219 x}{263677440} &    \frac{263677440}{553781219} & 0.476140
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\left|\frac{\cos x}2\right|$ is periodic with period $\pi$ and attains a maximum of $\frac12$, while $|\tan^{-1}x|$ is strictly increasing over all $\mathbb R^+$. Furthermore, we note that $|\tan^{-1}\pi/2|>\frac12$ already, whereas $\left|\frac{\cos x}2\right|$ is strictly decreasing over $(0,\pi/2)$.

The original equation thus has exactly one positive solution, which does not have an elementary expression; it is the solution of $\cos x=2\tan^{-1}x$, and is approximately $0.476147$.

Comment: How did you get .4761 I need the prove of equation

Comment: @user You cannot get an equation. You must use numerical methods.